# Extract comma-separated values from JSON Records within a List with PowerQuery

Tags: json, list, record, powerquery

As part of a tool I am creating for my team I am connecting to an internal web service via PowerQuery.

The web service returns nested JSON, and I have trouble parsing the JSON data to the format I am looking for. Specifically, I have a problem with extracting the content of records in a column to a comma separated list.

**The data**

[image]

As you can see, the data contains details related to a specific "race" (`race_id`). What I want to focus on is the information in the `driver_codes` which is a List of Records. The amount of records varies from 0 to 4 and each record is structured as `id: 50000` (50000 could be any 5 digit number). So it could be:

`id: 10000
id: 20000
id: 30000`

As requested, an example snippet of the raw JSON:

```
<race>
    <race_id>ABC123445</race_id>
    <begin_time>2018-03-23T00:00:00Z</begin_time>
    <vehicle_id>gokart_11</vehicle_id>
    <driver_code>
        <id>90200</id>
    </driver_code> 
    <driver_code>
        <id>90500</id>
    </driver_code>
</race>
```

I want it to be structured as:

```
10000,20000,30000
```

**The problem**

When I choose "Extract values" on the column with the list, then I get the following message:

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type
>   Text.

If I instead choose "Expand to new rows", then duplicate rows are created for each unique driver code. I now have several rows per unique race_id, but what I wanted was one row per unique race_id and a concatenated list of driver codes.

**What I have tried**

I have tried grouping the data by the race_id, but the operations allowed when grouping data do not include concatenating rows.

I have also tried unpivoting the column, but that leaves me with the same problem: I still get multiple rows.

I have googled (and Stack Overflowed) this issue extensively without luck. It might be that I am using the wrong keywords, however, so I apologize if a duplicate exists.

**UPDATE: What I have tried based on the answers so far**

I tried Alexis Olson's excellent and very detailed method, but I end up with the following error:

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "id" to type Number. Details:
>
> Value=id
>   Type=Type

The error comes from using either of these lines of M code (one with a List.Transform and one without):

```
= Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"race_id", "begin_time", "vehicle_id"},
 {{"DriverCodes", each Text.Combine([driver_code][id], ","), type text}})
= Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"race_id", "begin_time", "vehicle_id"},
 {{"DriverCodes", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([driver_code][id], each Number.ToText(_)), ","), type text}})
```

NB: if I do not write `[driver_code][id]` but only `[id]` then I get another error saying that column `[id]` does not exist.

Comment: I'm having difficulty reproducing your error. Can you provide a sample JSON string you're trying to do this with?

Comment: Added. Please see my edit. Does that make it clearer for you?

Comment: Sure. That's XML, not JSON though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the JSON equivalent to the XML example you gave:

```
{"race": {
    "race_id": "ABC123445",
    "begin_time": "2018-03-23T00:00:00Z",
    "vehicle_id": "gokart_11",
    "driver_code": [
      { "id": "90200" },
      { "id": "90500" }
    ]}}
```

If you load this into the query editor, convert it to a table, and expand out the Value record, you'll have a table that looks like this:

[image: Start Table]

At this point, choose Expand to New Rows, and then expand the `id` column so that your table looks like this:

[image: Intermediate Table]

At this point, you can apply the trick @mccard suggested. Group by the first columns and aggregate over the last using, say, max.

[image: Group By]

This last step produces M code like this:

```
= Table.Group(#"Expanded driver_code1",
              {"Name", "race_id", "begin_time", "vehicle_id"},
              {{"id", each List.Max([id]), type text}})
```

Instead of this, you want to replace `List.Max` with `Text.Combine` as follows:

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type",
              {"Name", "race_id", "begin_time", "vehicle_id"},
              {{"id", each Text.Combine([id], ","), type text}})
```

Note that if your `id` column is not in the text format, then this will throw an error. To fix this, insert a step *before* you group rows using `Transform Tab > Data Type: Text` to convert the type. Another options is to use `List.Transform` inside your `Text.Combine` like this:

```
Text.Combine(List.Transform([id], each Number.ToText(_)), ",")
```

Either way, you should end up with this:

[image: Final Table]

Comment: I have edited my question to include the results based on your answer. Could you have a look at that? Your code really looks like the right approach, but I still get an error similar to the one I had before.

Comment: It looks like you skipped the step where you expanded past the `driver_code` to the `id` column. Check that your table looks like my second image before you do the grouping.

Comment: Ahhh. Of course. Now that I expand the column, it works perfectly. I wish I had enough rep to +1 your brilliant answer, but you will have to make to with an accept. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Amazing. This solution was the most elegant and straightforward to understand. You saved my week.

Answer (score 1):

An approach would be to use the Advanced Editor and change the operation done when grouping the data directly there in the code.

First, create the grouping using one of the operations available in the menu. For instance, create a column"Sum" using the Sum operation. It will give an error, but we should get the starting code to work on.

Then, open the Advanced Editor and find the code corresponding to the operation. It should be something like:

{{"Sum", each List.Sum([driver_codes]), type text}}

Change it to:

{{"driver_codes", each Text.Combine([driver_codes], ","), type text}}

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I tried your solution but I get error  "Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Text. Details: Value=List Type=Type". Maybe it has to do with the structure of the JSON. I added that to my question. Could you have a look at it to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: It appears that Alexis Olson has addressed this new issue on his answer, in his last instruction.